# How can I make a smoother my heightmap? (Perlin noise, openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, heightmap

I generate 2D perlin noise and I'm doing it terrain. But I have a problem with this. It's too gradual.

[image: Here it is]

[image: And polygon]

I tried `x`,`z` coordinates are divided or multiplied but doesn't work. How can I solve this problem without tessellation shader?

EDIT:

fragment shader code:

```
#version 430

in vec3 pos;
in vec2 text;
in vec3 norm;

layout(binding=3) uniform sampler2D texture_1;
layout(binding=4) uniform sampler2D texture_2;
layout(binding=5) uniform sampler2D texture_3;

vec3 lightPosition = vec3(-200, 700, 50);
vec3 lightAmbient = vec3(0,0,0);
vec3 lightDiffuse = vec3(1,1,1);
vec3 lightSpecular = vec3(1,1,1);

out vec4 fragColor;
vec4 theColor;

void main()
{

    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition) - normalize(pos); 
    float cosTheta = clamp(dot(normalize(lightVector), normalize(norm)), 0.5, 1.0);

    if(pos.y <= 120){
        fragColor = texture2D(texture_2, text*0.05) * cosTheta;
    }
    if(pos.y > 120 && pos.y  <  150){
        fragColor = (texture2D(texture_2, text*0.05) * (1 - (pos.y-120)/30) +  texture2D(texture_3, text*0.05) * ((pos.y-120)/30))*cosTheta;
    }
    if(pos.y >= 150)
    {
        fragColor = texture2D(texture_3, text*0.05) * cosTheta;
    }
}
```

vertex shader code:

```
#version 430

in layout(location=0) vec3 position;
in layout(location=1) vec2 textCoord;
in layout(location=2) vec3 normal;

out vec3 pos;
out vec2 text;
out vec3 norm;


uniform mat4 transformation;

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = transformation * vec4(position, 1.0);
    norm = normal;
    pos = position; 
    text = position.xz;
}
```

Comment: With no code to go on, it's kinda hard to make any meaningful suggestions. Look at the individual pieces that make up your final color. Without knowing what your shaders looks like... no, that's it. I can't possibly post anything more specific. Look at the individual elements composing your final color and figure out which one(s) aren't working quite right.

Comment: You could make a pass to alter the points so that they're an average of the points around it (perhaps with some variability)

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an 8bit heightmap which only gives you 256 different elevations. You could try using 16bit greyscale or encode the height in rgb.

Comment: No. I don't load the heightmap. Perlin noise generated by hte height. But it is true the perlin noise return between -1 and 1. I change this to 0...255 for example: heightMap[i][j] = noise.perlinNoise_2D(i, j) * 128 + 128

Comment: So what type is `heightmap` and how do you create your mesh from this map.

Comment: Perlin noise implemented on bases of http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm 

this, and
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
  {
heightMap[i][j] = noise.perlinNoise_2D(i, j) * 128 + 128;
}
}

And now realy have 256 different height.

Comment: @FarkasMáté: Whether you loaded the map or generated it, you still only have 8 bits of precision. That's 256 distinct height elevations.

Comment: Yes I see. That was the problem. When I create vertices (vec3) the 'y' coordinates I cast to (int). And here I lost lot of intermediate height maybe.  So I remove this cast and it does work. Thank you very much for all your help!!  :)